# Magento 2.4.2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (url)

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.2, optimization, advanced-bundling

I'm following the instructions to get advanced JS bundling done. I have been doing this over a year without much difficulty. This time around, I find the error below and I would like to know if there is a solution to this. Thanks.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (url)
```

A line appearing after this line seems to give some clue as to what could be done to fix this.

```
If the source uses ES2015 or later syntax, please pass "optimize: 'none'" to r.js and use an ES2015+ compatible minifier after running r.js. The included UglifyJS only understands ES5 or earlier syntax.
```

The command below causes this error.

```
r.js -o build.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have some Javascript that is using ES6 or newer syntax and the version of UglifyJS does not support this.

It looks like version 3.13.0 does support ES6 so I suggest either upgrading to that, using an alternative. If that is not possible then you will need to re-write your JS to ES5 standards. To find the code responsible try searching your codebase for `name (url)`.

If it is already written to ES5 then you most likely have a syntax error so you'll need to find that.

Another option is to set optimize: "none" although I'm unsure what affect on the bundle that will have, it sounds like the files will not be minified if that value is "none".